# Can highcharts export POST a JSON options object instead of SVG?

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

I'm using highcharts-convert.js with phantomjs, and I'm having some text-overlapping issues when exporting the charts.

I believe the reason is Chrome on OSX renders fonts differently than my ubuntu server does.  So when the client's browser builds the SVG the text does not overlap (I have indeed confirmed this by capturing the POST and rendering the svg in Chrome), but when phantomjs renders the text on ubuntu its slightly wider so there is overlap.

I believe that if I export the options JSON rather than SVG, ubuntu will lay out the text according to its own font rendering, and nothing will overlap.

Does that make sense?  If so, how can I get highcharts to POST the options JSON rather than SVG?

I have this process that I can use to rig everything up, but it feels like there should be a better way...

```js
var chart = graphContainer.find(".graph-body div").highcharts();
var chartOptions = chart.options;
delete chartOptions.chart["renderTo"];   // this creates a circular reference

// provide extra options to override the chart's defaults here...
$.extend(chartOptions.chart, {backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", spacingLeft: 30, spacingRight: 30});

// wrap this up and POST it to the server...
console.log(JSON.stringify(chartOptions));
```

Comment: You have setup your own server, right? In that case, can't you add some POST page which will get JSON from AJAX, and then pass that object to phantom JS? So then on server you would use simple: `phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options.json -outfile chart.png`

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I am trying to set up.  But it's complicated because some options are passed to highcharts as functions (customer renderer functions for example), which have to be serialized into JSON and then back again on the server.

Comment: In that case I think you need to update highcharts-convert.js file. Find line ~369 - there chart is created. Now look through options to find your string functions and eval them.

Comment: Could you explain, how you modify your highcarts-convert.js file to eval the functions?